# Windows Batch "dir" command change?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, scripting

It seems unlikely, but I can only assume that something changed recently (this week) during a Windows Update.

At least two scripts that use to work now do not.  That is, scripts I use almost every day. Among them are my script builder for a small Java project.

```
dir /s /B /a:-d *.java >sources.txt

"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\javac %javaopts% -d ..\classes -nowarn -classpath %clspath% @sources.txt
```

Standard, right?  Except "dir" no longer removes the directory name (per a:-d) as it used to.  Hence, my java compile script is failing.  (Why yes, I also use Eclipse.)

As in, the files listed in the sources contain the full path of the file ("C:\X\Y\Z\src\foo.java").  By manually remove the path preceding src ("c:\x\y\z") the same script works.  I've tried different case on the options, changing around the javac command, but I always get the parsing error "unknown option c:...:) because of the full paths identified in the sources file.

Regardless of why it happened, it's happening now and I am looking for an alternative which I haven't found yet.  A simple alternative - I probably could write a loop that removes anything before "src" (for example) - but these two commands are cited many, many places so I thought I'd save someone the time and post myself.

Comment: You are mistaken. When using the recursive `/S` option, the output is **always** returned with the full paths.

Comment: The `D` attribute of the `DIR` command is for listing directories contained within the current directory or not listing directories contained within the current directory when using the minus.  Has nothing to do with the path names being listed with the files.

Comment: /a:-D is supposed to remove the directories.  And, I believe it used to.  Note the minus D)

Comment: `/A:-D` doesn't remove the directories. Instead of returning every subdirectory and file whose basename matches your `*.java` glob, it returns only files matching it. As already stated, it returns those files as fully qualified paths. If you want only files and for them to be returned relative to the current directory, you could run the command through a [tag:for-loop], save the individual items as variables, then expand and replace the current directory in the variable values with nothing. Alternatively, use `ForFiles`, i.e. `ForFiles /M *.java /S /C "Cmd /C Echo @RelPath">"sources.txt"`.

Comment: @StevenPowell, the `/A:-D` does remove directories from the listing of the contents of the directory you are executing the `DIR` command against.  If you have a folder named `Steve` and file named `Steve.txt` in a folder then `/A:-D` will not list the folder named `Steve`.  It has nothing to do with the file paths being listed with the file names.  That is what the `/S` option is doing.

Comment: The issue has come up when passing the sources.txt to javac.  If I remove the fully qualified name, it works.  Otherwise, it gives me a "C:\x" is an invalid option error.  I commands I posted are pretty well advertised.  My findings were that if I removed the fully qualified name, then javac would work.  I also believed that I had this worked "as-is" for a few weeks, then ... something changed.  All of that being said, the ForFiles command by @compo works fine in that it emulates what the *Nix "find ." command does.  It's just not what's been posted. Fully qualified names are ok in javac, yes?

Answer (score 0):

The folks who commented are correct. the argument `/a:-D` does not remove directories.
See [dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir).

When you think abut it, if you want to "build a small Java project" (using the 2nd line of your script), why would you want to delete the folders that contain the java files whose fully qualified file names are written to `sources.txt`?

> /s: Lists every occurrence of the specified file name within the
>   specified directory and all subdirectories.
>
> /b: Displays a bare list of directories and files (fully qualified names), with no additional information (i.e, date, time, size are omitted).
>
> /a[[:]]: Displays only the names of those directories and
>   files with the attributes that you specify.

If you use `/a` specifying the
`-d` attribute, `Directories` (`d` means `Directories`) are `Not` displayed (`-` means `Not`)

The bottom line is that `sources.txt` will have a bare list of fully qualified file names matching the mask `*.java` at and below whatever the current directory is at the time you run your script